# Why are Kubernetes Custom Resource Definitions cluster wide

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

Hello StackOverflow users,

I've started working in the Kubernetes space recently and saw that [Custom Resource Definitions(CRDs) types are not namespaced and are available to to all namespaces.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/)

I was wondering why it isn't possible to make a CRD type scoped to a namespace. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65551#issuecomment-400909534 for a discussion of this issue.

A particular CRD can define a custom resource that is namespaced or cluster-wide, but the type definition (the CRD itself) is cluster-wide and applies uniformly to all namespaces.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response Jordan, the github issue you provided answered my question, thank you!